Scriptural reference where the name of god helps us to lessen the intensity of bad karmas or completely dissolve it
As I have learnt from Sri Ramakrishna paramahamsa and Sri Sri Sarada Devi (his consort) they claim that by chanting gods name one can lessen the intensity of the bad karmas. By that they mean if we were to lose our legs then instead of it we would get a pin prick.
Also it is a common talk within the internet and common Indian household that chanting om namah shivai and ram nama can dissolve all our sins. So my first question is is this true?
My second question is , like Ramakrishna said , can chanting any stotras or mantras of god resolve our papas and bad karmas gradually?
My last question is know specifically those mantras and stotras that have assured that chanting that will reduce bad karmas and papa karmas and will not give bad consequences in our life .
(please try to give a scriptural reference to any answers or thoughts provided.)

Few old references: 1, 2

Answer to the first question
Power of the name of the Lord

Sri Suka said, 'Austerity, charity, Japa and such other disciplines
efface only the effects of sins, but not the heart, the source from
which they spring. Even that source, the sinful tendency, is effaced
by the service of the Lord's feet. As the fire burns up a heap of
fuel, the name of the Lord of holy fame, chanted whether with
knowledge of its greatness or without it, destroys the sins of man.'

Srimad Bhagavata Purana, VI.2.17-18
Answer to second question
The mantra must be obtained from a Guru. Any mantra won't do.
Importance of obtaining a mantra from a Guru

Innumerable are the Mantras; they but distract the mind. Only that
Mantra which is received through the Grace of the Guru gives all
fulfilment.

Kularnava Tantra, Purascharana, Readings by M.P. Pandit
Answer to the third question
Consult a Guru for getting your mantra.

The pre-amble to the Vishnu Sahasranama says
https://sanskrit.today/shloka-vishnu-13/
Shloka - Vishnu 13

यस्य स्मरणमात्रेण जन्मसंसारबन्धनात् ।


विमुच्यते नमस्तस्मै विष्णवे प्रभविष्णवे ॥


I salute to that Lord, Achuta(who is faultless), and by simply remembering Him or uttering His name, all deficiencies in my activities disappear and my penance attains completion instantly. (Alternate) Respects to that Lord Vishnu, the Almighty, the mere contemplation of whose Name assures liberation from the bondage of samsAra, the cycle of births and deaths.

